# JS fetch con POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, fetch

El siguiente código únicamente me envía por método GET:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['datos'])){
    echo json_encode($_REQUEST);
    exit();
}
?>

<script>
async function envia_post(){
    let _datos = {'a1':'uno','a2':15,'a3':16,'datos':25};
    const post = {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(_datos),
      headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
    };
    let fetchResponse = await fetch('index.php?datos=1', post);
    let data = await fetchResponse.json();
    console.log(data);
}
</script>

<div onclick="envia_post();">Click!</div>
```

Como le quite el `?datos=1` y deje únicamente el `POST`, no envía nada. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Referencias:
[mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `fetch()` tienes al menos dos formas de capturar sus datos enviados:

1. Con `php://input`:

```
<?php
if ($data = file_get_contents('php://input')){
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}
?>
<script>
async function envia_post(){
    let _datos = {'a1':'uno','a2':15,'a3':16,'datos':25};
    const post = {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(_datos),
      headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
    };
    let fetchResponse = await fetch('index.php?datos=1', post);
    let data = await fetchResponse.json();
    console.log(data);
}
</script>

<div onclick="envia_post();">Click!</div>
```

2. Enviándolos en forma de **FormData** con `POST`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) and !empty($_POST)){
    echo json_encode($_POST);
    exit();
}
?>

<script>
async function envia_post(){
    let _datos = {'a1':'uno','a2':15,'a3':16,'datos':25};

    var formData = new FormData();
    for ( var key in _datos ) {
        formData.append(key, _datos[key]);
    }

    const post = {
      method: "post",
      body: formData,
    };
    let fetchResponse = await fetch('index.php', post);
    let data = await fetchResponse.json();
    console.log(data);
}
</script>

<div onclick="envia_post();">Click!</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, ambas funcionan... :)

Comment: He hecho un cambio en la segunda solución para que no sea necesario saber ningun dato enviado previamente.